# Syntax for rounding up in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

What is the syntax to round up a decimal leaving two digits after the decimal point?

Example: 2.566666 -> 2.57

Answer (score 16):

If you want regular rounding, you can just use the `Math.Round` method. If you specifially want to round upwards, you use the `Math.Ceiling` method:

```
Dim d As Decimal = 2.566666
Dim r As Decimal = Math.Ceiling(d * 100D) / 100D
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is how I do it:

```
Private Function RoundUp(value As Double, decimals As Integer) As Double

    Return Math.Ceiling(value * (10 ^ decimals)) / (10 ^ decimals)

End Function
```

Answer (score 7):

[Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) is what you're looking for. If you're new to rounding in .NET - you should also look up the [difference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131275.aspx) between [AwayFromZero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ToEven](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rounding. The default of ToEven can sometime take people by surprise.

```
dim result = Math.Round(2.56666666, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`System.Math`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math_members.aspx), specifically [`Math.Round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx), like this:

```
Math.Round(2.566666, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Math.Round()`, as suggested by others, is probably what you want.  But the text of your question specifically asked how to "roundup"[sic].  If you always need to round up, regarless of actual value (ie: 2.561111 would still go to 2.57), you can do this:

```
Math.Ceiling(d * 100)/100D
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic function for rounding up is Math.Ceiling(d), but the asker specifically wanted to round up after the second decimal place. This would be Math.Ceiling(d * 100) / 100. For example, it may multiply 46.5671 by 100 to get 4656.71, then rounds up to get 4657, then divides by 100 to shift the decimal back 2 places to get 46.57.

Answer (score 1):

I used this way:

```
Math.Round(d + 0.49D, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.Ceiling((14.512555) * 100) / 100
```

Dot net will give you `14.52`. So, you can use above syntax to round the number up for 2 decimal numbers.

Answer (score -2):

I do not understand why people are recommending the incorrect code below:

```
Dim r As Decimal = Math.Ceiling(d * 100D) / 100D
```

The correct code to round up should look like this:

```
Dim r As Double = Math.Ceiling(d)
```

1. Math.Ceiling works with data type Double (not Decimal).
2. The * 100D / 100D is incorrect will break your results for larger numbers.
3. Math.Ceiling documentation is found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx

Comment: Math.Ceiling has two overloads; one for decimal and one for double.

Comment: the only point that i don't know is true or not is point 2 that you make. maybe you could provide and example? the other 2 points you make (1 and 3) are incorrect. here is the math.ceiling documentation at its highest level, which will show 2 overloads: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math.Ceiling(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: While Math.Ceiling can take either decimal or double it always returns _"Returns the smallest integral"_ (from the docs you link).  OP specifically asks for rounding to two decimal places.  So they want a decimal/double back, not an integer.  So Math.Ceiling won't work by itself