# Reduce a decimal precision by one place, always rounded up

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to simplify a decimal value to always have one fewer digits. The result should always round up, never down.

For example, if I have `8.81` the should should be `8.9`. If I have `2.566666` the result should be `2.56667`.

How can I do this?

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862274/syntax-for-rounding-up-in-vb-net

Comment: 1) Do you mean a value in a variable of type Decimal, or just some fractional amount in a Double? 2) Where did the number come from? (It could be easier if it started out as a string.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. My starting number is always 2 digits so i can use this:

`Dim Number as double = 8.81 Dim result as double = Math.Ceiling(Number * 10)/10D`

Thanks to @dbasnett for the seggestion.